# Get count of second-degree foreign-key entities in Django

Tags: django, django-models

We have a data model with three basic models:

- Group
- Activity
- Participant (User model)

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Activity(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(to=Group, reverse_name="activities")
```

I want to know how many times people participated in group activities, so I would like to count participants for all activities regardless of uniqueness.

How can I sum the counts of all participants for all activities related to a given group?

[image: example data set with aggregation]

Comment: Can you add your models to the question? Do you want to count all unique participants or sum the counts from each activity?

Comment: I updated the question with the clarifications you requested @IainShelvington. I am hoping to sum all the counts of participants, without concern for uniqueness. Essentially, I want to know how many times people participated in group activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood the question correctly (judging from the diagram I think so). This query would return the sum of the number of participants (not distinct) of all the activities of group 1:

```
User.objects.filter(activity__group_id=1).count()
```